# Why does this method throw a Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, json, parsing, segmentation-fault, token

I am using the [jsmn JSON parser](http://zserge.bitbucket.org/jsmn.html) ([source code](https://raw.github.com/noct/jsmn/master/jsmn.c)) to get some text from a JSON.  jsmn stores the data in tokens, but the tokens **do not hold any data**, they just point to the token boundaries in JSON string instead. For example, jsmn will create tokens like:

- Object [0..31]
- String [3..7], String [12..16], String [20..23]
- Number [27..29]

This method is used to retrieve the actual characters between those values (for string objects):

```
char* getTextFromJSON(const char *json)
{
    if (!json) return NULL;

    json_parser p;
    #define N_TOKENS 15  // this normally would be at the start of the file
    jsontok_t tokens[N_TOKENS];

    initJsonParser(&p);
    int err parseJson(&p, json, tokens, N_TOKENS);
    if (err) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Error parsing JSON: %d\n", err);
    return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N_TOKENS; ++i) {
        jsontok_t *key = &tokens[i];
        if (!memcmp("utterance", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) {
            ++key;
            return strndup(&json[key->start], (size_t)(key->end - key->start));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here are some JSON examples that would be thrown into the parser:

- `{"status":0,"id":"432eac38858968c108899cc6c3a4bade-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"test","confidence":0.84134156}]}`
- `{"status":5,"id":"695118aaa3d01dc2ac4aa8054d1e5bb0-1","hypotheses":[]}`

Upon passing the first example JSON to the method, I get the expected value of "test" returned from the method.  However, upon passing the empty JSON to the method, I get a Segmentation fault on the 8th iteration of the `for` loop on the conditional `if` statement.

Any suggestions?

Here are the hex values:

```
key->start: 0x00000000
key->end - key->start: 0x00000046
key->start: 0x00000002
key->end - key->start: 0x00000006
key->start: 0x0000000A
key->end - key->start: 0x00000001
key->start: 0x0000000D
key->end - key->start: 0x00000002
key->start: 0x00000012
key->end - key->start: 0x00000022
key->start: 0x00000037
key->end - key->start: 0x0000000A
key->start: 0x00000043
key->end - key->start: 0x00000002
key->start: 0x3A7B3188
key->end - key->start: 0x7A0F0766
```

Comment: Do you really want to pass `&jason[..]` to `memcpy`?

Comment: @UchiaItachi There is no `memcpy` in that method...

Comment: Put a `printf()` statement  in your loop to print the values for `(key->start)`, and `(key->end - key->start)` in hex (ie: `printf("0x%08X", val)`. I'm leaning towards your input string, `json`, being shorter than expected, and you are passing an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Dogbert Edited them into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tokens[]` array is uninitialized before you pass it to `parseJson()`, so once you iterate beyond the last token (the seventh one in your second example) you're trying to run `memcmp()` on uninitialized nonsense address values.  That's causing your seg fault.  Initialize `tokens[]` to something and then check for that initialization value in the start/end fields during your `for()` loop.

For example, I'd probably initialize `tokens[]` to zero ( via `memset(&tokens, 0, sizeof(tokens));` ) and during each iteration of the loop check for length zero ( `key->end - key->start` ) to see if the token is actually valid before passing it to `memcmp()`.  Bail out of the loop with a `break;` if the token has length zero.

(Or, if a token can have a legitimate zero-length, use some other value.)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it got me the closest to the solution.  I did as you suggested, but I also added a test case for a blank token (`if (!memcmp("", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) return NULL;`).  Now the code doesn't give a Segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** After looking at the source code...

```
for (i = parser->toknext; i < num_tokens; i++) {
    jsmn_fill_token(&tokens[i], JSMN_PRIMITIVE, -1, -1);
}
```

It initializes all of the structures but ->start and->end will equal -1, which is why memcmp is failing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N_TOKENS; ++i) {
    jsontok_t *key = &tokens[i];
    if (key->start == -1) return NULL;
    if (!memcmp("utterance", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) {
        ++key;
        return strndup(&json[key->start], (size_t)(key->end - key->start));
    }
}
```

Checking for a -1 value in ->start or ->end should be sufficient.

Comment: Still getting a Segmentation fault :/

Comment: @syb0rg - You never check the result of the parseJson(...), you should only proceed if that function returns JSMN_SUCCESS.

Comment: I've updated the method that introduces a test condition.  It still gives a Segmentation fault.

Comment: +1 for the help you gave. I've introduced the test cases you suggested and my code now works properly.  The other answer just brought me a bit closer to completely dependent code.  Thanks for your help!